# Converter Program for Hex to Dec and Binary

Tags: java, user-interface, jframe, converters

Given my code below, I'm a little confused as to what I am missing in order to allow it to function so that when the user inputs their hexadecimal value with a maximum of five digits, they will get their binary equivalent and the decimal equivalent. I thought the code at the bottom automatically converts given a certain number in hex. Also would it be difficult to store the binary values in an array?

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.InputMethodListener;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.NumberFormat;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
public class ConvertPanel {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame ("Hexadecimal to Binary and Decimal.");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);   
    frame.getContentPane().add(new NumberConverter());
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);

    }
}

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.InputMethodListener;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.NumberFormat;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;



public class NumberConverter extends JPanel {
    private JLabel binaryLabel = new JLabel();
    private JLabel totalone = new JLabel();
    private JLabel totaltwo = new JLabel();
    private JLabel decimalLabel = new JLabel();
    private JTextField  hexdecString = new JTextField();
    private JButton convert;


    public NumberConverter() {

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 300));
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        JLabel converterName = new JLabel("Hexadecimal Input");


        convert = new JButton ("Convert");

        convert.addActionListener (new ButtonListener());


        JPanel panelName = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2,2));
        panelName.add(converterName);
        panelName.add(hexdecString);
        add(panelName, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add (convert);


        JPanel totalPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,3));
        totalPanel.add(new JLabel("Binary:"));
        totalone = new JLabel("---- ---- ---- ---- ----");
        totalPanel.add(totalone);
        totalPanel.add(binaryLabel);

        JPanel totalPanel2 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2,3));
        totalPanel2.add(new JLabel("Decimal:"));
        totaltwo = new JLabel("------");
        totalPanel2.add(totaltwo);
        totalPanel2.add(decimalLabel);

        JPanel south = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2,1));
        south.add(totalPanel);
        south.add(totalPanel2);
        add(south, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    }        

    private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener
    {
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event){


            Integer n = Integer.valueOf(hexdecString.getText(), 16);
            decimalLabel.setText(String.valueOf(n));
            binaryLabel.setText(Integer.toBinaryString(n));
        }  {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But what is calling `convertInput`?

Comment: Nothing at the moment. How could I go about doing so? Am I missing listeners such as button listener for convert?

Comment: Did you mean `Integer n = Integer.valueOf(hexdecString.getText(), 16);`?  You've typed 20.

Comment: That would be my general suggestion...

Comment: Is that all I'm missing?

Comment: I got it. I'm going to modify my original code. How come the "convert" button is so large and when the output is on the screen it is not aligned with my ---- ---- ---- ---- ----? I want it to replace that for the binary